# Странное поведение сервиса получения курса валют

Tags: xml, php

Есть [сервис получения валют](http://nbrb.by/Services/XmlExRates.aspx). Ранее все было нормально, все работало. Была функция  `simplexml_load_file();` которая парсила xml и выдавала курсы. С недавних пор появилась ошибка:

> `Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: http://nbrb.by/Services/XmlExRates.aspx:6: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: hr line 5 and body in /home/victumby/public_html/test.php on line 4`

Далее. Если открыть этот xml через файербаг, от мне показывает теги html, body, head, хотя это xml файл.

Вопрос: что происходит? Есть версия, что что-то в кодировках.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется что вам просто выдаётся не XML и из-а этого ошибка.